# Prevent compound dupes for PATH variables

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, idempotent

I happen to be using NODE_PATH, and we have this standard thing:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:~/.foo/node_modules
```

calling this line in the bash script a few times, I get a bunch of compound duplication, such that NODE_PATH is filled with duplicate items.

What is the best way to do something like:

```
NODE_PATH=$(remove-dupes $NODE_PATH:~/.foo/node_modules)
```

The remove-dubes routine would have to know that its argument was a colon delimited string.

Comment: http://linuxg.net/oneliners-for-removing-the-duplicates-in-your-path/

Comment: A better idea is to figure out why you are executing that line more times than necessary, and avoid it.

Comment: @chepner, yes and no, at some point, you will need an "if exsts, do nothing, if not initialize" type check.  This kind of thing accomplishes it to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ! grep -q node_modules <<eof
$NODE_PATH
eof
then NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:~/.foo/node_modules
fi
```

1. Do a heredoc with current NODE_PATH: this allows you to avoid a pipe/subshell
2. grep -q: this stops grep after first match, and quiets output
3. !: if match not found
4. Do your code

Also good:

```
if awk 'BEGIN {exit ARGV[1] ~ "node_modules"}' "$NODE_PATH"
then NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:~/.foo/node_modules
fi
```

Comment: ok, but it seems like you are just grepping for node_modules, not an actual literal dupe in the string? e.g., what if I wanted to add ~/.bar/node_modules to the path?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a few shell functions for `ksh93` that handles path-like variables.  This is a version that I believe will work in both `bash` (release 4.3?) and `ksh93`. The funky names of the nameref variables (`typeset -n`) are due to Bash's unwillingness to use a local nameref to a variable that has the same name as the nameref itself (this *may* be fixed in Bash release 4.5).

```
function delete_from_path
{
    typeset -n dfp_variable="$1"
    typeset value="$2"

    if [[ "$dfp_variable" == "$value" ]]; then
        variable=""
    else
        dfp_variable="${dfp_variable/#${value}:/}"
        dfp_variable="${dfp_variable/%:${value}/}"
        dfp_variable="${dfp_variable//:${value}:/:}"
    fi
}

function suffix_path
{
    typeset -n sp_variable="$1"
    typeset value="$2"

    if [[ -z "$sp_variable" ]]; then
        sp_variable="$value"
    elif [[ "$sp_variable" != "$value" ]]; then
        delete_from_path sp_variable "$value"
        sp_variable="$( printf '%s:%s' "$sp_variable" "$value" | tr -s ':' )"
    fi
}

function prefix_path
{
    typeset -n pp_variable="$1"
    typeset value="$2"

    if [[ -z "$pp_variable" ]]; then
        pp_variable="$value"
    elif [[ "$pp_variable" != "$value" ]]; then
        delete_from_path pp_variable "$value"
        pp_variable="$( printf '%s:%s' "$value" "$pp_variable" | tr -s ':' )"
    fi
}

function _exists_in_path
{
    typeset -n eip_variable="$1"
    typeset value="$2"

    typeset tmppath="$eip_variable"

    delete_from_path tmppath "$value"

    if [[ "$tmppath" == "$eip_variable" ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

function consolidate_path
{
    typeset -n cp_variable="$1"

    typeset IFS=':'
    typeset tmpvar
    typeset element

    for element in $cp_variable; do
        if ! _exists_in_path tmpvar "$element"; then
            suffix_path tmpvar "$element"
        fi
    done

    cp_variable="$tmpvar"
}
```

To "consolidate" the `PATH` variable, i.e. to remove all duplicates, one would use

```
$ consolidate_path PATH
```

To add `$HOME/local/bin` to the end of the path:

```
$ suffix_path PATH "$HOME/local/bin"
```

This works for all `PATH`-like variables (variables whose values are `:`-separated paths).

Simple examples:

```
$ p="a:b:c:b"
$ consolidate_path p
$ echo "$p"
a:b:c

$ suffix_path p "a"
$ echo "$p"
b:c:a

$ delete_from_path p "c"
$ echo "$p"
b:a
```

Answer (score 0):

Such lists are usually managed piecemeal. So normally, you'd want to handle de-duping at the point where each path is added (usually prepended) to the list. Just like for `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The original question didn't mention a preferred shell... so I've provided for a couple of them.

---

GOAL

Solutions are idempotent: if called twice, result on `NODE_PATH` must not change on second invocation.

---

## For zsh (now default for MacOS)

**zsh** has built-in support for this. Work with the indexed array form (like `PATH` vs `path`):

```
typeset -TUx NODE_PATH node_path
```

The `-T` option "ties" the two vars. `-U` guarantees uniqueness. `-x` handles exporting.

Then prepend to `NODE_PATH` as follows: (two options presented):

```
node_path=("~/foo" $node_path)
    -OR-
node_path[1,0]="~/foo"
```

Exporting and entry uniqueness are just automagically handled for `NODE_PATH`.

---

## For bash (default for many Linux distros)

Define a simple bash function for prepending, as follows:

```
_node_path_prepend() {
    NODE_PATH=:$NODE_PATH
    export NODE_PATH=$1${NODE_PATH//:$1/}
}
```

Invoke the function:

```
_node_path_prepend "~/foo"
```

This approach should work for most modern shells (including zsh), and it could be easily adjusted to support appending a path, instead of prepending it.

---

One Caveat

*(Consider "`~/foo/sub:~/foobar`": prepend "`~/foo`" to get an unexpected result: "`~/foo/subbar`"!!)*

Subdirs and certain sibling paths might be an issue.
In practice, I've ***never*** encountered this as a problem.

But for completeness, here's a more robust (complicated) function:

```
_node_path_prepend() {
    NODE_PATH=:${NODE_PATH//:/::}:
    NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH//:$1:/}
    NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH//::/:}
    export NODE_PATH=$1${NODE_PATH%?}
}
```

Comment: I was answering the question of how to **prevent** duplicates, as mentioned in the title and example. The Q used append rather than prepend. So, here's how to do that -- In zsh: `node_path+="~/foo".` -- In bash, change last line of function to: `export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH#?}$1`